# Achieve sequence number in concurrency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to the transaction isolation levels. I am a beginner to SQL as well.
I have two stored procedures like below.

```
  create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spupdaterecordinfintab]
      @IDS BIGINT
  AS
     BEGIN
begin try
begin transaction

declare @id bigint
set @id = (select [Seedno] from [dbo].[SeedNo] where [Type] = 'abc')+1
DECLARE @INUM NVARCHAR(50) 
SET @INUM = 'ABC'+ CAST(@id AS nvarchar(20))

UPDATE [dbo].[exchTab]
SET 
    [INUMBER] = @INUM

    WHERE [id] = @IDS

UPDATE [dbo].[SeedNo]
SET
  [Seedno] = @id
WHERE [Type] = 'INV'

EXEC spNEWROECORDINTOfintab @IDS
commit
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction

end catch

    END


create PROCEDURE [dbo].spNEWROECORDINTOfintab 
   @IDS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN    
    declare @id bigint
    set @id = (select [Seedno] from [dbo].[SeedNo] where [Type] = 'abc')+1

    DECLARE @INUM NVARCHAR(50) 
    SET @INUM = 'ABC'+ CAST(@id AS nvarchar(20))

    insert into [dbo].[exchTab]
    values( @INUM,123.78,1)

    UPDATE [dbo].[SeedNo]
    SET [Seedno] = @id
    WHERE [Type] = 'INV'
END
```

I want to achieve sequence numbers in inumber in my exchTab tbale. How do I achieve this when multiple users executing 
[spupdaterecordinfintab] stored procedure at same time(concurrency)? Which transaction isolation level is suitable ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems grossly wrong. If you need a sequence with atomic updates (that is, for which updates do not interfere with each other), you should be using a [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use code as follows in the `SELECT` instruction, forcing an exclusive lock on it:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].spNEWROECORDINTOfintab 
@IDS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    declare @id bigint
    SELECT @id = [Seedno] from [dbo].[SeedNo] WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK) where [Type] = 'abc'
    SET @id = @id + 1
    DECLARE @INUM NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @INUM = 'ABC'+ CAST(@id AS nvarchar(20))

    insert into [dbo].[exchTab]
    values( @INUM,123.78,1)

    UPDATE [dbo].[SeedNo]
    SET
       [Seedno] = @id
    WHERE [Type] = 'INV'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

There are 2 key parts in this proc. The first one is the very first `SELECT`, that contains the `ROWLOCK` and `XLOCK` hints. Those tell the DB engine to impose an exclusive lock on the affected rows (instead of the default shared lock for reads). This blocks any other concurrent processes on this instruction, forcing them to wait for the proc to finish. `ROWLOCK` only blocks the actual row read, as choosen by the `WHERE` clause. Note that, for that to work, you will need an unique index on that column, otherwise you'll end up locking the whole table.

The other important part is the transaction management. I've added a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the very beginning and a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` at the end. The reason for those is that the locks are held only for the duration of the transaction. If left out, each statement constitutes its own transaction, so other readers would be able to mess with the table and get repeated/skipped numbers.